# Cakephp Update datafield with ENUM

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0

i dont know why i am getting this issue. i have set the datatype to ENUM. when i set its valye 'Y','N'
then its working fine for one field. Now i have another field named type ( ENUM) = '0','1','2'

Now i want to change/update its value then its not working.

here below i have mentioned my query

```
$BiddersItem = $this->paginate("BiddersItem", array_merge(array("BiddersItem.type"=>"2"), $filter));
```

that is the piece of the code for the update. i hope you can understand this. 
i have set my debug on so check the query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `event_mang_db`.`bidder_item_master` AS `BiddersItem` LEFT JOIN `event_mang_db`.`item_master` AS `Item` ON (`BiddersItem`.`item_id` = `Item`.`item_id`) LEFT JOIN `event_mang_db`.`atendee_master` AS `Attendee` ON (`BiddersItem`.`atendee_id` = `Attendee`.`atendee_id`) LEFT JOIN `event_mang_db`.`event_master` AS `Event` ON (`BiddersItem`.`event_id` = `Event`.`event_id`) WHERE **`BiddersItem`.`type` = 2** AND `BiddersItem`.`event_id` = 2
```

---

issue is that when you set BiddersItem`.`type` = '2' then its work fine.

suggest me the solution
thanks in advance

Comment: change your column datatype to set rather than using enum, cakephp has unknown problem with enum datatype

Comment: BUT ITS working fine with other field for which i have value 'Y','N'

Comment: yes if you use only 2 values then enum might work but if you are having more than 2 values it might give you error. I have faced this error long before.

Comment: It doesn't work because your enum list contains numeric values, they won't be qoted as you need. What happens if you write the condition like this: `=> "'2'"`?